# Django queryset always reload instances

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm having some problems with a homemade caching descriptor and debugging I came up to this (strange) behaviour I can't figure out. Consider the following Django1.7 model (actually very simplified compared to my original project):

```
class Step(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey('Game', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}'.format(id(self))
```

If in terminal I run `python manage.py shell` and then

```
In [1]:ss = Step.objects.filter(game=1)

In [2]: ss
Out[2]:[<Step: 139934116973392>, <Step: 139934116971472>]

In [17]: ss[0]
Out[17]: <Step: 139934117084944>

In [18]: ss[0]
Out[18]: <Step: 139934117098512>

In [19]: ss[0]
Out[19]: <Step: 139934117098320>
```

I don't understand why `ss[0]` id keeps changing... is it standard behaviour? It seems that at each time `ss` is accessed all step instances era reloaded from the database (and so it is since `django.db.connection.queries` contains always new items).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are, as the queryset is not fully evaluated and cached (printing it does not cache the results). As a result, the query is executed every time you access `ss[0]`:

```
>>> ss = Step.objects.filter(game=1)
>>> ss
[<Step: 139934116973392>, <Step: 139934116971472>]
>>> print ss._result_cache
None
>>> bool(ss)
True
>>> print ss._result_cache
[<Step: 139934117084944>, <Step: 139934117098512>]
```

Only when the queryset is fully evaluated (by iterating over it or calling `len`, `list` or `bool`), will the results be cached.

Comment: Really interesting and counterintuitive (imo), is this (and possibly other "strange" behaviour) documented anywhere?

Comment: I can't find anything particularly on caching, but the docs have a [topic on evaluation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated). Just remember that the result is only cached if the whole queryset is evaluated, and that `repr` does *not* evaluate the whole queryset (rather it takes a slice, which *might* include the whole queryset but doesn't cache it either way).

Comment: Thanks, evaluating the whole queryset with bool() fixed all my issues.